# Parse broken HTML with golang

Tags: html, xpath, go

I need to find elements in an HTML string. Unfortunately the HTML is pretty much broken (e.g. closing tags without an opening pair).

I tried to use XPath with *launchpad.net/xmlpath* but it can't parse an HTML file so damn buggy.

How can I find elements in a broken HTML with golang? I would prefer using XPath, but I am open for other solutions too if I can use it to look for tags with a specific id or class.

Comment: For those stumbling on this issue now, note that the xmlpath project has moved (and improved) to https://gopkg.in/xmlpath.v1 .

Answer (score 21):

It seems [net/html](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html) does the job.

So that's what I am doing now:

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "log"
    "bytes"
    "gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2"
)

func main() {
    brokenHtml := `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1 id="someid">My First Heading</h1><p>paragraph</body></html>`

    reader := strings.NewReader(brokenHtml)
    root, err := html.Parse(reader)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    html.Render(&b, root)
    fixedHtml := b.String()

    reader = strings.NewReader(fixedHtml)
    xmlroot, xmlerr := xmlpath.ParseHTML(reader)

    if xmlerr != nil {
        log.Fatal(xmlerr)
    }

    var xpath string
    xpath = `//h1[@id='someid']`
    path := xmlpath.MustCompile(xpath)
    if value, ok := path.String(xmlroot); ok {
        log.Println("Found:", value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over all `Node`s which match a given XPath? Thanks.

Comment: iter := path.Iter(xmlroot)
    for iter.Next() {
        log.Println(iter.Node().String())
    }